# Git - Unable to execute git commands - index.lock file keeps appearing

Tags: git, github

When I try to commit my changes in cmder (command line for git) index.lock keeps (re)appearing in my .git directory under my application folder.

I tried

```
1) rm .git/index.lock
2) git clean -f  .git/index.lock
3) opening and closing my cmder
4) terminating all git processes running
5) restarting my machine
```

to no avail
no matter which step

I run I keep getting the error

> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g. an
>   editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes are
>   terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process may have
>   crashed in this repository earlier: remove the file manually to
>   continue.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: This is not a solution—the `index.lock` file should not be getting stuck in the first place and this suggests that the version of Git you have downloaded is broken—but I'll note that `git clean -f .git/index.lock` is never going to work here. `git clean` is meant to apply only to work-tree files. Files inside `.git` are never work-tree files.

Comment: I used an unorthodox resolution.  I ran file history in Windows 10 and restored the directory to a working version.  That cleared the issue.